# How to filter the array of objects by multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For this question
I already got the answer I wanted by myself but
My solution is long and got multiple looping.

So I am asking here because I want an alternative solution.

The thing I want is
I want to filter the array by 3 properties. The condition is that if the user fill the properties  function need to search for that property. If user left the property blank, We can skip to filter that property

Here is my example data

```
let arrays = [
    {
        id: "29",
        title: "Race event 2018",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing",
        industry: "Retail",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        title: "Foundation",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "D365",
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        title: "More disruption",
        solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: null,
        integration: null,
    },
    {
        id: "36",
        title: "Building blocks",
        solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "37",
        title: "Delicious icecream",
        solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "CRM",
    },
];
```

Here is the search function

What I want is if user don't give the property to search I want to return the original array, If user don't fill `solutionToSearch` I wanna search for object that match `industryToSearch` & `integrationToSearch`,

At the same time if user don't fill `industryToSearch` and leave it blank
I want to search objects that. match with `solutionToSearch` & `integrationToSearch` property , ViceVersa for all 3 values

```
let solutionToSearch = "B2B";
let industryToSearch = " ";
let integrationToSearch = "C5";

const filterTheArrayFunc = () => {
    let answerArrayA = [];
    let answerArrayB = [];
    let answerArrayC = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        if (solutionToSearch === "" || solutionToSearch === " ") {
            answerArrayA = arrays;
        } else {
            for (let y = 0; y < arrays[i].solutionType.split(",").length; y++) {
                if (arrays[i].solutionType.split(",")[y].trim() === solutionToSearch)
                    answerArrayA.push(arrays[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < answerArrayA.length; i++) {
        if (industryToSearch === "" || industryToSearch === " ") {
            answerArrayB = answerArrayA;
        } else {
            if (answerArrayA[i].industry === industryToSearch) {
                answerArrayB.push(answerArrayA[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < answerArrayB.length; i++) {
        if (integrationToSearch === "" || integrationToSearch === " ") {
            answerArrayC = answerArrayB;
        } else {
            if (answerArrayB[i].integration === integrationToSearch) {
                answerArrayC.push(answerArrayB[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(answerArrayC);
};

filterTheArrayFunc();
```

As you can see I am looping multiple times and making a lot of variables that are not necessary.
I want to improve my code , Can someone help please.

Comment: it's not entirely clear what the goal is. [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a function, that function can filter based on whatever criteria you want, including checking an object for any combination of properties.

Comment: if you already have a working solution you should post on codereview.stackexchange instead of here.

Comment: More broadly, any time there's duplicated code, it can generally be extracted to a method. In addition, things like `foo === '' || foo === ' '` can be shortened to forms like `!foo.trim()` or similar. There are *many* ways this code could be reduced and improved, which make the most sense depends on context. On the plus side, even minimal effort would make it much better.

Comment: @DaveNewton If user fill `solutionToSearch` or `industryToSearch ` or `integrationToSearch` I want to look for all the property, If user skip one I wanna skip that property, if skip two I wanna skip two properties and search for object that match the all the given properties, Can you show me your shortened version for me

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve with the data, as the code is not super clear. Fairly sure you can do this in a few lines with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but I don't fully understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object with the same keys as properties as fin the objects to compare with.

This solution takes `null` or `undefined` without searching.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "29", title: "Race event 2018", solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing", industry: "Retail", integration: "C5" }, { id: "30", title: "Foundation", solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "D365" }, { id: "31", title: "More disruption", solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ", industry: null, integration: null }, { id: "36", title: "Building blocks", solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "C5" }, { id: "37", title: "Delicious icecream", solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "CRM" }],
    search = Object
        .entries({ solutionType: "B2B", industry: " ", integration: "C5" })
        .filter(([, v]) => v && v.trim()),
    result = array.filter(o => search.every(([k, v]) => !o[k] || o[k].includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)..

```js
let arrays = [
    {
        id: "29",
        title: "Race event 2018",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing",
        industry: "Retail",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        title: "Foundation",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "D365",
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        title: "More disruption",
        solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: null,
        integration: null,
    },
    {
        id: "36",
        title: "Building blocks",
        solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "37",
        title: "Delicious icecream",
        solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "CRM",
    },
];

let solutionToSearch = " ";
let industryToSearch = " ";
let integrationToSearch = "C5";

const filterTheArrayFunc = () => {
    return arrays.filter(obj=>
      (!solutionToSearch.trim() || (obj.solutionType || "").includes(solutionToSearch.trim())) &&
      (!industryToSearch.trim() || (obj.industry || "").includes(industryToSearch.trim())) &&
      (!integrationToSearch.trim() || (obj.integration || "").includes(integrationToSearch.trim()))
    );
};

var filtered = filterTheArrayFunc();
console.log(filtered);
```

You could further improve this by passing the parameters rather than relying on variables from an outer scope. Additionally, you could filter by property names rather than creating a new variable to define search parameters for every property name.

```js
let arrays = [
    {
        id: "29",
        title: "Race event 2018",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing",
        industry: "Retail",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        title: "Foundation",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "D365",
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        title: "More disruption",
        solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: null,
        integration: null,
    },
    {
        id: "36",
        title: "Building blocks",
        solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "37",
        title: "Delicious icecream",
        solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "CRM",
    },
];

function filterTheArrayFunc(arr, params){
    var filter_keys = Object.keys(params);
    return arrays.filter(obj=>{
      return filter_keys.reduce((match, key) => {
        let value = params[key].trim();
        if(!match) return false;
        if(!obj[key] || !obj[key].includes(value)) return false;
        return match;
      }, true);
    });
};

var filtered = filterTheArrayFunc(arrays, {
  solutionType: "B2B",
  integration: "C5"
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Its give me error when I search for these values `let solutionToSearch = " ";
let industryToSearch = " ";
let integrationToSearch = "C5";`

Comment: Getting kinda hacky with these solutions.. I fixed that implementation, but I also provided a better one.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arrays = [
    {
        id: "29",
        title: "Race event 2018",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing",
        industry: "Retail",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "30",
        title: "Foundation",
        solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "D365",
    },
    {
        id: "31",
        title: "More disruption",
        solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: null,
        integration: null,
    },
    {
        id: "36",
        title: "Building blocks",
        solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "C5",
    },
    {
        id: "37",
        title: "Delicious icecream",
        solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ",
        industry: "Distribution",
        integration: "CRM",
    },
];

const filterByParams = (arr, params) => arr.filter(e => Object
    .entries(params)
    .every( ([k,v]) => e[k].includes(v.trim()) ))


const res = filterByParams(arrays, {
  solutionType: "B2B",
  integration: "CRM",
  title: " "
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

I really like Nina's universal and scalable approach, but she was possibly a bit too lenient whith respect to a "missing property" in the target object. Maybe by leaving out `!o[k] ||` the code will produce the results OP had in mind?

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "29", title: "Race event 2018", solutionType: "B2C, B2B, Marketing", industry: "Retail", integration: "C5" }, { id: "30", title: "Foundation", solutionType: "B2C, B2B, CMS, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "D365" }, { id: "31", title: "More disruption", solutionType: "CMS, Marketing, ", industry: null, integration: null }, { id: "36", title: "Building blocks", solutionType: "B2C, Marketing, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "C5" }, { id: "37", title: "Delicious icecream", solutionType: "B2B, CMS, Marketing, ", industry: "Distribution", integration: "CRM" }],
    search = Object
        .entries({ solutionType: "B2B", industry: " ", integration: "C5" })
        .filter(([, v]) => v && v.trim()),
    result = array.filter(o => search.every(([k, v]) => o[k].includes(v)));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```